# Not able to run Google Signin and Facebook Signin on on IOS Simulator. No errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xcode, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Not able to run Google Signin and Facebook Signin on on IOS Simulator. No errors. But when I run the apple signin that is working fine. Using Firebase Authentication with ionic react and capacitor.

```
const signInWithApple = async () => {
    // 1. Create credentials on the native layer
    const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithApple();
    // 2. Sign in on the web layer using the id token and nonce
    const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');
    const credential = provider.credential({
      idToken: result.credential?.idToken,
      rawNonce: result.credential?.nonce,
    });
    const auth = getAuth();
    return await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
  };

const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        // 1. Create credentials on the native layer
        const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithGoogle();
        // 2. Sign in on the web layer using the id token
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(result.credential?.idToken);
        const auth = getAuth();
        return await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      };
    
const signInWithFacebook = async () => {
        // 1. Create credentials on the native layer
        const result = await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithFacebook();
        if (!result?.credential?.accessToken)
          throw new Error("Something went wrong");
        // 2. Sign in on the web layer using the access token
        const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.credential?.accessToken);
        const auth = getAuth();
        return await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
      };
```